# Do we need the "a" in "Let's create a data set X"?

Tags: articles

Suppose, there's no data set X yet. Let's create a data set called X. Let's create a data set X. Do we need the "a" before "data set" in the previous sentence?

Comment: Depends on the context/intent.

Comment: The context is we are about to initialize a data set called X and assign it some value. Or a set of values rather.

Comment: Have you already described the nature of the data set?

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose, there's no data set X yet. Let's create a data set called X.
> Let's create a data set X. Do we need the "a" before "data set" in the
> previous sentence?

**1.**

If you have already discussed X - even in theory - then you can use its ***name***. Names don't require an article.

**Example**

*Soon we will create a dataset and call it X.*
(5 minutes go by)
*Now we are ready.  Let's create data set X.*  (X already has a name)

---

2. 

If you haven't mentioned X then you must refer to "a dataset" and then name it afterwards.

*Let's create a data set X.*

This is equivalent to

*Let's create a data set **and name it** X.*

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.